# Running sqlldr or sqlplus from AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, sqlplus, sql-loader

I am trying to automate database deployment .
This have sqlplus and sqlldr commands running from shell.

Now i need to convert this into lambda. Do we have a compatible python library or java library that allow to run these commands on serverless architecture.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved via SSM Documents. Connecting ec2 which have these utilities installed